# Problems with loading resources Spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

i collided with some problems when i was writing web app.
When i use URL like this *http://localhost:8080/user* i have no problems and my app work correctly, but when i use URL such as *http://localhost:8080/some-intermediate-node/user* i have pages without any style and java-script code.
Belong i show my dispatcher servlet config

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.excbooks.controller")
public class ServletConfig  extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**").addResourceLocations("/css");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/js/**").addResourceLocations("/js");
    }
    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver setupViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix("");
        resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        return resolver;
    }
    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }
}
```

and my controller

```
@Controller
public class MainController {
    {
        BasicConfigurator.configure();
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/d/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String login(Model model){
        return "log-in.html";
    }
    @RequestMapping(value = "/d/user", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String userProfile(Model model){
        User user = new User();
        user.setId(new BigInteger("1"));
        user.setUsername("Sashko");
        model.addAttribute("user",user);
        return "index.jsp";
    }
}
```

Link to my JSP index *https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B42ezhAKqwZlcUEyVkR5amNIaDg/view?usp=sharing*

Comment: Share code of index.jsp please?

Comment: ok. Here https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B42ezhAKqwZlcUEyVkR5amNIaDg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Post that in the question.

Comment: @JB Nizet, It is actual jsp.

Comment: And? How does that prevent from posting its content in the question?

Comment: As @JBNIZET suggesred add index.jsp content in the question as you have added java code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your JSP, I suspect the javacsript/css files are pulled in roughly like...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/my.css">
<script src="js/my.js"></script>
```

The issue is that the `href` and `src` attributes specify relative URLs.  They correctly point to your files when the URL is http://localhost:8080/user, but when the URL is http://localhost:8080/some-intermediate-node/user the browser will look for...

- http://localhost:8080/some-intermediate-node/css/my.css
- http://localhost:8080/some-intermediate-node/js/my.js

respectively.

Change the `href` and `src` attributes so that they start with a forward slash (`/`) character.

Answer (score 0):

Change CSS and javascript href to /css/** and /js/**

For example :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="/js/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
```